# Importing data from excel 2007 ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, excel-2007, import-from-excel

hello is there a way to import data from excel 2007 file? it is working with excel 2003 but i am getting errors when trying with 2007 is there any reference i should follow, please advice i am still new @ this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string will be conditional for your office 2007 and 2003 support

```
 if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fup.FileName) == ".xls")
    {
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/upload/temp/File.xls") + "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    }
    else if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fup.FileName) == ".xlsx")
    {
        connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/upload/temp/File.xlsx") + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer :

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Excel 2007  -- http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Excel 2003 -- http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel